# Has Biden or his staff/selectees discussed plans of how to handle the physical White House and Secret Service, re: COVID?

Tags: united-states, covid-19, joe-biden, political-transitions, secret-service

By this, I don't mean how the President-Elect plans to handle COVID, big-picture, but rather how he and his staff are planning on dealing with the actual physical White House, the West Wing and the Oval Office, in light of news reports of President Trump and various staff members and his Secret Service detail having, or having had confirmed cases of COVID.

It might be easy to suggest emptying the White House and sanitizing the whole thing, but there are many relatively priceless and irreplaceable items in it as well as that someone has to always be there. Plus the fact that it's not all *that* big a building, underground rooms not-withstanding. I'm curious to the details of that part of the transition.

Comment: I don't think they would have to empty the entire building to sanitize it and I have not heard of that as a solution to an infection breaking out in an area.

Comment: Disinfections have been performed at the WH even during the Trump administration https://www.foxnews.com/politics/white-house-cleaning-crews-trumps-return , https://www.whitehouse.gov/briefings-statements/update-health-safety-precautions-taken-within-executive-residence/ Unfortunately, you can't disinfect people that way.

Comment: Not an answer because it doesn't come from the Biden team, but here's a article discussing some of the concerns relevant to this question: https://slate.com/technology/2020/11/white-house-quarantine-pre-biden.html

Comment: @Fizz Trump says you can :-(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Rather than being handled by the Biden team itself, this appears to be being handled by the General Services Administration (GSA). An agency spokesman gave a statement to Politico on December 9th covered [here](https://www.politico.com/news/2020/12/09/biden-covid-safety-transition-444040), the full content of which has been published by the Daily Mail [here](https://www.dailymail.co.uk/news/article-9040033/White-House-deep-cleaning-Joe-Biden-moves-in.html):

> "GSA will thoroughly clean and disinfect the building spaces between
> the administrations and ensure that everything is up to standard.
> Cleaning will include, but is not limited to, all furniture, flooring,
> window treatments, handrails, door knobs, light switches, countertops,
> elevator buttons, restroom fixtures and dispensers, door handles and
> push plates, and lighting fixtures."

In addition, both articles point to the [contract](https://www.usaspending.gov/award/CONT_AWD_47PM1021C0002_4740_-NONE-_-NONE-) granted to Didlake Inc. by the GSA beginning on November 3rd, for:

> East and West Wing disinfectant misting services due to COVID at the
> White House. Contractor shall provide the services per the scope of
> work for a performance period of 1 year.